How can I get a user's location when my iOS app is killed or terminated in Swift?
I've been trying to retrieve the user's location while the app is terminated or killed, but haven't had any luck so far. I've implemented the usual approaches for background location updates, but they only work while the app is in the foreground or background—not when it's completely terminated.
I believe apps like Apple Maps and Google Maps can achieve this, but I’m not sure how they do it. Below is the code I've tried so far. Can someone please suggest how to track location even when the app is killed or terminated?
Below is my current code
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var lblLatitude: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblLongitude: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblSavedLocation: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblArrayCount: UILabel!

    var locManager = CLLocationManager()
    var currentLocation: CLLocation!
    private var backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid
    private var timer: Timer?

    var locationDataSaved = [String]()
    var count = Int()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Request Always Authorization
        locManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locManager.delegate = self

        // Start monitoring location
        startMonitoring()
        loadAndPrintSavedLocations()
    }

    func startMonitoring() {
        locManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        locManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
        locManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func getLocationData() {
        if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse || CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedAlways) {
            guard let currentLocation = self.locManager.location else {
                return
            }

            lblLatitude.text = "\(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)"
            lblLongitude.text = "\(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)"

            let newLocationData = ["latitude": "\(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)", "longitude": "\(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)"]

            // Load existing locations
            var savedLocations = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "locationDataSaved") as? [[String: String]] ?? []

            // Check for duplicates
            let isDuplicate = savedLocations.contains { location in
                location["latitude"] == newLocationData["latitude"] && location["longitude"] == newLocationData["longitude"]
            }

            // If not a duplicate, add to the saved locations
            if !isDuplicate {
                savedLocations.append(newLocationData)
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue(savedLocations, forKey: "locationDataSaved")
                print("Location added: Latitude: \(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude), Longitude: \(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)")
                
                // Call postLocation to send the location to server
                postLocation(location: currentLocation)
            } else {
                print("Duplicate location, not added.")
            }
        }
    }

    private func loadAndPrintSavedLocations() {
        if let savedLocations = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "locationDataSaved") as? [[String: String]] {
            var locationText = ""
            count = savedLocations.count
            lblArrayCount.text = "\(count)"
            for location in savedLocations {
                if let latitude = location["latitude"], let longitude = location["longitude"] {
                    print("Saved Location: Latitude: \(latitude), Longitude: \(longitude)")
                    locationText += "Latitude: \(latitude), Longitude: \(longitude)\n"
                }
                lblSavedLocation.text = locationText.isEmpty ? "No saved locations." : locationText
            }
        } else {
            print("No saved locations found.")
        }
    }

    func startBackgroundTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(callApiInBackground), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func callApiInBackground() {
        // This function will be called every 5 seconds
        postLocation(location: currentLocation)
    }

    func stopBackgroundTimer() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }

    deinit {
        stopBackgroundTimer()
    }
}

extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        // Use the last known location
        if let location = locations.last {
            self.currentLocation = location
            getLocationData() // Process the location data

            // Start the background timer when location updates are received
            if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .background {
                startBackgroundTimer()
            }
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("LocationManager \(error)")
    }
}

extension ViewController {
    private func postLocation(location: CLLocation?) {
        guard let location = location else { return }

        if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .background {
            backgroundTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(withName: "locationTaskName", expirationHandler: {
                UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTask)
                self.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid
            })

            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                self.postRequest(location: location) { [weak self] in
                    guard let self = self else { return }
                    UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTask)
                    self.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid
                }
            }
        } else {
            postRequest(location: location)
        }
    }

    private func postRequest(location: CLLocation, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        // Call your API
        callApi()
        completion?()
    }
}

extension ViewController {
    func callApi() {
        // The API URL
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://new-dev.artoon.in:8888/rwl-app-cms/Custom_script/ios_test") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }

        // Create a URL session
        let session = URLSession.shared

        // Create a data task
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            // Check for errors
            if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            // Check for valid response
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
                print("Invalid response")
                return
            }

            // Check for data
            guard let data = data else {
                print("No data returned")
                return
            }

            // Handle the data (convert to string for demonstration)
            if let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("Response: \(responseString)")
            }
        }

        // Start the task
        task.resume()
    }
}


@JoakimDanielson - This is a demonstration example, which is why I have included this timer. Could you please provide guidance on the correct approach and steps to achieve this? Thank you.

Your app can't do anything when it is terminated, because it is terminated.  You can use significant location change monitoring to try and relaunch your app when the user moves. Depending on what you are trying to do, a location push extension or visit monitoring  may be useful

Yes, you can track location even when your iOS app is terminated , but there are specific conditions under which this is allowed. Apple has strict guidelines on privacy and background location usage, and tracking the location while the app is terminated is limited to certain cases like significant location changes or region monitoring.
1.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
2.Region Monitoring (Geofencing)
Note:
You must request the .always authorization for location updates to work in the background or when the app is terminated
